# How can I find my PlanetSide 2 server ping?

Tags: planetside-2

Is there any way I can find my ping in PlanetSide 2?

I've been looking for a while and can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.  Your only option is to ping the server from the command line.

- Briggs (AU): 69.174.220.23
- Ceres (EU): 195.33.132.169
- Cobalt (EU): 195.33.132.169
- Lithcorp (EU): 195.33.132.168
- Mallory (EU): 195.33.132.168
- Miller (EU): 195.33.132.172
- Woodman (EU): 195.33.132.169
- Connery (US West): 64.37.174.140
- Genudine (US West): 64.37.174.143
- Helios (US West): 64.37.174.140
- Jaeger (US East): 199.108.194.38
- Mattherson (US East): 199.108.194.38
- SolTech (US East): 199.108.194.39
- Waterson (US East): 199.108.194.41

These are liable to change in the future (especially after a server reset) so it may be necessary to use wireshark to obtain the IP.

Comment: another site says woodman has ip 195.33.132.167 so someone is wrong here

Comment: These addresses for the eu servers no longer work :(

Answer (score 2):

Hi There i wrote a small program that tells you which server is the best for you, eliminating the manual labor behind pinging each server separately.

[Here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/416220/ARGlag.rar) is the link for the full package(43.4MB)
or

[Here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/416221/ARGlag_small_version.rar) is the smaller one(26.2KB)

the larger file just has added dependency files like dotnetfx40client and a windows driver
if the small one doesn't work, just download the big one and install the abovementioned

Answer (score 0):

If you know the game server's IP address then you can use the command `ping` in command prompt to ping the server.

To open command prompt Start > Run > Type `cmd` and press Enter. In the command prompt window type `ping (IP address)` or `ping (server name)`. For example: `ping 193.211.145.197` or `ping abc.com`

If you have trouble using command interface,then you can do ping test easily from websites sites like http://www.whoisxy.com/ping.aspx. If you don't know the IP address you can find it by using Wireshark.